# Why boolean value is not changing?

Tags: java

I am learning java step by step:

I have a practice problem [problem statement link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery) and this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test, numProcess = 0;
    boolean checkString ;
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    test = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        String original = sc.nextLine();
        checkString = checkPalindrome(original);
        while (!checkString) {
            char oldchar = original.charAt((original.length() - 1));
            char newchar = alpha.charAt((original.indexOf(oldchar) - 2));
            original = original.substring(0, original.length()-1)+ newchar;
            checkString = checkPalindrome(original);
            numProcess++;
        }
        System.out.println(numProcess);
    }

    sc.close();
}

public static boolean checkPalindrome(String original) {
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = (original.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        newString += original.charAt(i);
    }
    return (newString.equals(original));
 }
}
```

the problem is when we try as input,

1. `"abc"` as string(IN WHILE LOOP) 1st iteration makes original = abb
    then goes to function which returns false(that is right)
2. in 2nd iteration original = aba which should return checkString = true;
3. and next time while loop should be bypassed but it again enters into
    while loop (I tried this in debugger)and makes throws exception at
    line containing newchar(Index out of bounds) what is the problem ??

Comment: Please could you work on the formatting of your question to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = (original.length() - 1); i > 0; i--)
```

Your new string doesn't contains first character: the "abc" string will become to "cb". You should change your for condition to `i >= 0` or `i > -1`

Comment: same problem arises.. after changing to your suggestion @TEXHIK

Comment: So, use debug. Check what values have original and new strings at the return line, using breakpoints or `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If you put input as `abc`. Your code will throws an Exception

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
test = sc.nextInt(); // reading an int
```

While you are putting `abc`.

You are trying to find whether given String is palindrome, You can do it as following way easily.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String original) {
    StringBuilder sbOriginal = new StringBuilder();
    sbOriginal.append(original);
    StringBuilder sbReverse=sbOriginal.reverse();
    return  sbOriginal.toString().equals(sbReverse.toString());
}
```

[Run This code](http://ideone.com/SAErIE).

Comment: put as test and string in one line(with space in between) it will work(take only for 1 test case)

Comment: @user3985848 you can run my code using the link i have provided. Just run it. You can see this is working fine

Comment: I edited as per your code but happens same as previous

Comment: @user3985848 what are you trying to do with for lopp?

Comment: that is for test cases

Comment: I figured out the problem ..i have posted it below...thanks for your function isPalindrome ...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was the real problem .. when reading string through scanner like as an example in the format testcase(how many int) and string(check for this string solution)
-> 1 abc .. the string will be readed as " abc" and not "abc" which is the error i made in accepting string as input by making sc.nextLine(); which should be used as sc.next();
so checkPalindrome was always returning false ...
hushhhhh!!! at last got the solution..

Vote up if I am right